# Mapping two different together on columns or index

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to ask a question that how can I mapping one dataframe into another dataframe. The idea is like this, I have two dataframes, one have around 1,500 pools, and other dataframe contains around 25 rows. I want to match the price from second dataframe, into the first dataframe, by using the rate range as a factor. Currently I do have any code written because I have no idea how to construct it. Would anyone gives me some idea about how can I started it.

Hi guys, I come back for more details. So here will be the elaborated information: Considering I have two dataframe, while dataframe A is a detailed spreadsheet contains the details of different bonds. Dataframe B provided the price of the bond. Now I want to map the price from dataframe B into dataframe A like following:

```
dataframe A: 

    Bond    Interest
0
1
2
3
4
5
......

dataframe B:
    Interest    Price
0
1
2
3
......

Combined dataframe: 
      Bond   Interest   Price
0
1
2
3
4
......
```

Noticed that dataframe A has thousands of rows, but dataframe only have 25. I want to use the interest from dataframe A to match the interest range in dataframe B, and mapping the price into the dataframe A. Does anyone have any solutions about this one. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you bring any examples? Hard to understand based in your description.

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal description and no examples provided. I think what you are searching for is `merge`. What you would do will look something like this:

```
# given df1, and df2
shared_col_name = 'rate range'

df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=shared_col_name )
```

You can refer to documentation for more details.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html